# Create fixed left column while right column continues scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen this on many websites where upon scroll one element becomes fixed while the elements next to it continue to scroll. I would like to understand how this works.

I created a pen for this: https://codepen.io/lisaschumann/pen/WNoJBbb where the left column is meant to be fixed when the right column starts to scroll. What am I missing here?

I used jQuery Code I had found on the issue, but ideally I would like to create this with JS.

**CSS, jQuery and HTML**:

```js
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top; // get initial position of the element

$(window).scroll(function () { // assign scroll event listener

    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // get current position

    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) { // apply position: fixed if you
        $('.fixme').css({ // scroll to that element or below it
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        });
    } else { // apply position: static
        $('.fixme').css({ // if you scroll above it
            position: 'static'
        });
    }

});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set additional styling options for the columns*/
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0;;">
    <div style="padding: 20px;">
        <h1> Test</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column" style="height: 300px;">
                <div class="fixme" style="background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; color: white; padding: 20px;">
                    <h2 style="margin:0 0 10px 0;">Headline</h2>
                    <span>Additional Info</span>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div style="height: 2000px; background-color: blue; border: 1px solid black; color: white; padding: 20px;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra. Eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare. Scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Amet nisl purus in mollis nunc. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam. Leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. Magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum.
                    <br>
                    Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla. Ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed. Lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi.
                    <br>
                    Orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non. Gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Tortor consequat id porta nibh. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus.
                    <br>
                    Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean. Sed odio morbi quis commodo. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed. Volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque. Volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.
                    <br>
                    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Interdum velit laoreet id donec. Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam. Neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat.
                    <br>
                    Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Et netus et malesuada fames. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. Urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Semper eget duis at tellus. Congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis.
                    <br>
                    Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.
                    <br>
                    Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id. Morbi quis commodo odio aenean.
                    <br>
                    Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Tristique magna sit amet purus. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare. Congue eu consequat ac felis. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec et.
                    <br>
                    Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Magna eget est lorem ipsum. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus. Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet. Varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Many thanks,
Lisa

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted or not? If you want to move header along with scroll, you can use `position: sticky`. Here you can find more: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-position-sticky

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.headerContainer {
  width: 35%;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top:10px;
  left:0;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row{
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2{
  margin:0 0 10px 0;
}



<body>
  <body>
    <h1> Test</h1>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="headerContainer">
        <h2>Headline</h2>
        <span>Additional Info</span>
      </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra. Eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare. Scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Amet nisl purus in mollis nunc. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam. Leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. Magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum.
        <br>
        Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla. Ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed. Lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi.
        <br>
        Orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non. Gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Tortor consequat id porta nibh. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus.
        <br>
        Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean. Sed odio morbi quis commodo. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed. Volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque. Volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet.
        <br>
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Interdum velit laoreet id donec. Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. Euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam. Neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat.
        <br>
        Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Et netus et malesuada fames. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. Urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Semper eget duis at tellus. Congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis.
        <br>
        Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.
        <br>
        Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id. Morbi quis commodo odio aenean.
        <br>
        Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Tristique magna sit amet purus. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare. Congue eu consequat ac felis. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec et.
        <br>
        Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra. Blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Magna eget est lorem ipsum. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus. Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet. Varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu.</p>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! I wanted the whole column on the right to stay as it is while the right column scrolls.